# WPF TextBlock Обрезка текста по центру

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

`TextBlock` предоставляет свойство `TextTrimming`, позволяющее обрезать текст, который не помещается в доступное для элемента пространство. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы обрезался не конец, а середина: вместо "text..." - "te...xt".

Есть 2 идеи как это реализовать: прикрепляемое свойство и наследование от класса `TextBlock`. В первом случае нужно ловить событие изменения текста и урезать его, но для этого мы должны знать сколько пространства доступно элементу, чтобы текст грубо не обрезался при отображении: как это понять не ясно. В случаи с наследованием от `TextBlock` переопределить метод `Measure` возможным не представляется, так как он является `sealed` (переопределив `Measure` мы бы могли получить доступ к `availableSize` и обрезать текст нужным нам образом).

То есть в любом случае важно понимать сколько места выделено элементу, чтобы текст не был обрезан визуально. Зная это значение мы можем обрезать текст так, как нужно нам, чтобы он полностью поместился в доступную область. Возможно вы подскажите идеи как действовать.

Comment: Отнаследоваться от текстблока и вырезать буковки до тех пор, пока размер текстблока не станет допустимым. Либо померять каждую буковку с символами и 3 точки, и математически вычислить, что надо вырезать, чтобы потом добавив вместо этого 3 точки, получилось как надо. Вот похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927501/texttrimming-from-left

Comment: "Отнаследоваться от текстблока и вырезать буковки до тех пор, пока размер текстблока не станет допустимым" - Вопрос в том как определить допустимый размер.

Comment: думаю [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs) или в соседних файлах можно найти, как трмминг работает

Comment: Смотрел уже по этой ссылке. Мне кажется всё происходит именно во время Measure, а как выяснилось переопределить этот метод не получится, так как он `sealed`.